# datatable jquery how to see data of the table in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I an using datatable by jquery(see documentation https://datatables.net/)

I want to see the attributes of the table, particularly the total count of rows of the table, I want to show this value in the html, How can I do this?

And how can I show the attributes of the tables in the console of chrome?

Comment: `console.log(table.rows().data().length);` and `console.log(table.settings().init());`

Comment: table? do you mean the id of the table? this didn't work

Comment: What I wrote in comment works for sure. `table = $("#example").DataTable()` - What do you want? Be more precise. "attributes" is a relative term.

Comment: if I do $("#example").DataTable() in the console, this return me "[]", Particularly I need the total row

Comment: `console.log($("#example").DataTable().rows().data())` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `console.log(result);`to your JavaScript code, result being the attribute you want to display. I copied that straight from my program so that should work for you. Good Luck.